# Getting 404 while hitting inhouse gitlab repo through rest api for getting all the branches of a project

Tags: git, rest, http, gitlab

We have an inhouse gitlab hosted repo in our organization and I am developer who does not have admin access to it.

However, I am the creator of this repository (`https://gitlab.gspt.net/payments/dss`) in `gitlab` and what I am trying to do is get all the branches within this repo through the rest api.

After doing some research online and going through this documentation (`https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/api/branches.html#protect-repository-branch`) I found that I can get all the branches of a repo using this command.

```
GET /projects/:id/repository/branches
```

**Example**

```
curl --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: 9koXpg98eAheJpvBs5tK" https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects/5/repository/branches
```

Here the PRIVATE-TOKEN in the header needs to be replaced with my private token, which I have already done, and now I am trying to access my inhouse gitlab repo using following command in Postman and I am getting `404`.

```
https://gitlab.gspt.net/api/v4/projects/payments/dss/repository/branches
```

Two problems here:

1. Not sure if my rest url is correct or not. I could not find the `id` of my project. I scanned through entire `gitlab` UI and could not find a trace of `id` anywhere. Hence using `NAMESPACE/PROJECT_NAME` in the http url which I happen to find somewhere in the documentation. Not sure if that is also correct though.
2. Not sure if my inhouse gilab admins have disable http rest api feature altogether. Never installed and administered a git repo ever, so no idea here as well.

Any guidance on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the project id you can use the [projects API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/api/projects.html#projects-api) searching for your repo name with the `search` parameter

The following bash script get the project id for the matched project name and perform the call to get your project branches. It uses [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) JSON parser to parse the JSON result :

```sh
#!/bin/bash

gitlab_host="https://gitlab.gspt.net"
private_token="9koXpg98eAheJpvBs5tK"
project_name="dss"

project_id=$(curl -s "$gitlab_host/api/v3/projects?search=$project_name&private_token=$private_token" | jq '.[0].id')

if [ "$project_id" == "null" ]; then
    echo "error could not find project id for project name $project_name"
    exit 1
fi

curl -s "$gitlab_host/api/v3/projects/$project_id/repository/branches?private_token=$private_token" | jq '.[]'
```

Comment: I tried your shellscript and I am getting this error. `./gitlab-id-finder.sh: line 7: jq: command not found`. Do I need to install anything. Just an FYI that I am  using Windows 7

Comment: yes it uses [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) to parse the json result, there is a windows release available